# kubectl exec commands are not recorded in pod's bash history

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way for the kubectl exec commands to be recorded by history command in the pod?
I want to collect all the commands executed on the container by monitoring history command.

Example:
`kubectl exec podname -n namespace -c container -- bash -c "ls"` ==> Can this be recorded by history command.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to clarify in order to get the full context of this behavior:

First, `kubectl exec` is a neat [API-based](https://itnext.io/how-it-works-kubectl-exec-e31325daa910) (*Warning: Medium member's story*) wrapper for [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

This is essential as it means that it'll use the Kubernetes API to relay your commands to Docker. This implies that whatever behavior, shell-related in this case, is directly linked to how Docker implemented the command execution within containers, and has not much to do with kubectl.

The second thing to have in mind is the command itself: `history`, which is an shell feature and not a separate binary.

The implementation depends on the shell used, but generally it caches the command history in memory before writing it to the  history file after the session is closed. This action can be "forced" using [`history` features](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Builtins) but can vary depending on the shell implementation and might not be an uniform, reliable approach while working with the `docker exec` command.

Considering these things and that your request seems to be aiming to monitor actions performed in your containers, maybe a better approach would be to use [Linux audit](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation/wiki) to [record commands executed by users](https://serverfault.com/a/336234/504596).

Not only this doesn't rely on the aforementioned points, it [writes logs to a file](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security_guide/sec-understanding_audit_log_files) and this allows you to use your [Kubernetes logging strategy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) to pick them, exporting them to whatever you're using as log sink, facilitating posterior inspection.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I thought your question was about capturing executed commands in the container, not whether the commands where executed via kubect/docker exec. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Inside the container i am able to capture the commands, no issues.
Outside the container, if a user executes commands using kubectl/docker  exec i need to capture those commands. Example:
kubectl exec podname -n namespace -c container -- bash -c "ls"
history command should show command "ls".

Comment: I understand. That's what I'm explaining in the answer, why `history` is not kept due the nature of the command and its reliance in the shell implementation. `history`, as normally used, will behave unreliably with `docker exec`, hence, the audit approach.